# Maps API was working, but has suddenly stopped. Plan to create SP for ERP

Tags: sql-server

Maps API was working, but has suddenly stopped.  Getting ??? ??? for Address and NULL for everything else.  This was working in the past.
Using this:

```
DECLARE @Address as varchar(100),
    @City as varchar(25),
    @State as varchar(2),
    @PostalCode as varchar(10),
    @Country varchar(40),
    @County varchar(40),
    @GPSLatitude numeric(18,9),
    @GPSLongitude numeric(18,9),
    @MapURL varchar(1024)
    





    SET @Address = '333 W 35th st'
    SET @City = 'Chicago'
    SET @State = 'IL'
```

--Build the web API URL

```
DECLARE @URL varchar(MAX)
SET @URL =  'https://www.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address='+
    CASE WHEN @Address IS NOT NULL THEN @Address ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @City IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @City ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @State IS NOT NULL THEN ', '+ @State ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @PostalCode IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @PostalCode ELSE '' END +
    CASE WHEN @Country IS NOT NULL THEN ', ' + @Country ELSE '' END+ 
    '&key=I_HAVE_A_VALID_API' 
SET @URL = REPLACE(@Url, ' ', '+')



---CREATE THE OATH REQUEST

DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @XML xml
DECLARE @Obj int
DECLARE @Result int
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int
DECLARE @ErrorMsg varchar(MAX)

Exec @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp',@Obj OUT

BEGIN TRY
    EXEC @Result  = sp_OAMethod  @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
    EXEC @Result  = sp_OAMethod  @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    EXEC @Result  = sp_OAMethod  @Obj, send, NULL, ''
    EXEC @Result  = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'status', @HTTPStatus OUT
    EXEC @Result  = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml', @Response OUT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE()
END CATCH

EXEC @Result = sp_OADestroy @Obj

IF (@ErrorMsg IS NOT NULL) OR (@HTTPStatus <> 200)
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorMsg = 'Error in spGeocode: ' + ISNULL(@ErrorMsg, 'Http result is: ' + CAST(@HTTPStatus AS varchar (10)))
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMsg, 16,1, @HTTPStatus)
    RETURN
END

 --CAPTURE THE RESPONSE
 BEGIN
 SET @XML = CAST(@Response AS XML)

 SET @GPSLatitude =@XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lat) [1]', 'numeric(18,9)')
 SET @GPSLongitude = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/geometry/location/lng) [1]', 'numeric(18,9)')
 SET @City = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="locality"]/long_name) [1]','varchar(40)')
 SET @State = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="administrative_area_level_1"]/short_name) [1]','varchar(40)')
 SET @PostalCode = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="postal_code"]/long_name) [1]','varchar(20)')
 SET @Country = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="country"]/short_name) [1]','varchar(40)')
 SET @County = @XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="administrative_area_level_2"]/short_name) [1]','varchar(40)')

 SET @Address = 
 ISNULL(@XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="street_number"]/long_name) [1]','varchar(40)'), '???') + ' '+
 ISNULL (@XML.value('(/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="route"]/long_name) [1]','varchar(40)'),  '???')

 SET @MapURL = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=' + CAST (@GPSLatitude AS varchar(20)) + '+' + CAST(@GPSLongitude AS varchar(20))

 END

 BEGIN
 SELECT @Address as Address,
 @City as City,
 @State as State,
 @PostalCode as Zip,
 @Country as Country,
 @County as County,
 @GPSLatitude as Lat,
 @GPSLongitude as lon,
 @MapURL as map

 END
```

Output was Address, Latitude and Longitude and MapURL.  Will eventually develop into a Stored Procedure in an ERP.
This worked a few weeks ago then had to shut it off for security reasons.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this code. What details are you passing over the URL? Does the API key still work? Have you tried call this using a debugging tool rather than SQL Server?

Comment: Just search the internet or this website to understand why the ole automation procedures are a TERRIBLE way to accomplish this.

Comment: In the RDBMS is the last place you should be doing calls to APIs. If you "must" then create a CLR function/procedure to do it. The OA objects are there for little more than compatibility purposes at this point.

Comment: OLE methods really shouldn't be called like this from SQL Server, it does nothing to help with stability, leaks and locking. Why record the return status from the `sp_OA` procedures when you don't check to see if any of those calls fail? At a minimum you should be checking those results for failure and invoking [sp_OAGetErrorInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-oageterrorinfo-transact-sql) to determine the problem. Consider ways to move this code outside SQL Server or, if you must keep it in SQL Server, convert it to SQL CLR instead.

Comment: The end result will be to provide a link within an ERP to project locations.  The script shown here tests the body of the final Stored Procedure.  The SP will pull data from the Project tables using SELECT commands and generate the Lat Lon and URL.  The details being passed are the project address. The code should generate Lat, Lon and the URL.  When first developed it worked.  Nothing changed and now it is generating NULLs.